# Can I record a phone call made to the office of my congressman or senator?

Tags: united-states, new-york-state, recording, phonecall, congress

Suppose I'm not too pleased with my Congressman's stance on an issue, and that I plan on calling his or her office.  **Is it legal to record a phone call made to the office of my Congressman (or Senator) in New York State, without telling them?**  Said office may be either their local office *or* their Washington office.  Does it make a difference if I make the phone call from within the state or district (maybe I'm in New Jersey for the day)?

And while we're at it, **is it legal to publish this audio recording online or send it to journalists?**

Comment: To their state office or DC office? Not sure if it matters, but it might.

Comment: Either.  I'll clarify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"One-party consent" law governs recording of conversations in [New York](http://codes.findlaw.com/ny/penal-law/pen-sect-250-00.html) state and under [federal law](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2511). What that means is that a conversation can be recorded, provided one of the parties consent. You can publish any legally-acquired material, or send it to journalists.

Comment: Even though I'm calling a member of public office (or, rather, their representative staff)?

Comment: @JesseTG one-party consent means that you can record any conversation you're participating in without the consent of the other party or parties. Therefore it doesn't matter whether the other party holds public office.

Comment: Ah, I see.  In that case, that answers my question, thank you!

Comment: @JesseTG: Note that some other states have two-party consent laws; in such states, you cannot record a conversation unless both parties agree.  It's conceivable that some states could have an exception when one of the parties is a public official, but I'm not aware of any.

Comment: @NateEldredge, in a phone call between a person who consents in a one-party-consent state and a person who does not consent in a two-party-consent state, which law governs?

Comment: That depends on which all-party state is involved. If it's California, California law wins (the Cal. Supreme Court has ruled). Probably the two-party state rules, in general.